What was the initial size of the file allocation table for a newly-formatted hard drive in MS-/PC-DOS 3.3?
Every attempt to discover this yields only loads of information about drive geometries and maximum volume size.
Also, if an additional FAT is needed (fragmenting it), how big are the additional extents?
I want to know so I can think about caching the FAT in 640K.

That will depend on the size of hard drive, the sector size and how you partition it to logical volumes, with which file system and cluster size. That determines the amount of clusters on drive and the size of FAT in some units. If you can give a typical numbers then there is a typical answer. The initial size is the amount it will ever need for the volume, as it can never grow in size as the size is fixed.

@Justme > That will depend on the size of hard drive, the sector size === When was sector size ever not 512? You may be thinking about cluster size. And BTW, the file allocation table could be extended (added to), but that required frafmenting it as two extents.

@Justme I don't know. Typically. An ST220. I just wanna get a general idea so I can think about whether the entire FAT could have been cached.

No I am not thinking of cluster size. Sometimes large hard drives were emulated to DOS with being quarter the amount of sectors with quadruple the native size. Rare but possible. Anyway, sector size may be irrelevant if we assume a cluster size regardless of sectors. OK, how large is an ST220 then?

@Justme 20M. I remember it fondly. Every PC I repaired had one. I hated to see it die when RLL was invented. But boy, RLL was magic!

@Justme I didn't know they did the CHS geometry trick with sector size!

"And BTW, the file allocation table could be extended (added to), but that required frafmenting it as two extents." Nonsense, a single FAT is always contiguous. It is possible to enlarge a file system or change its format, even without deleting all contained data, so yeah the FAT could be "extended". But the final result of that is always a contiguous FAT as no driver supports FATs split across two or more extents.

A cursory glance at a description of the FAT layout indicates it has to be contiguous. There is no provision for locating further discontiguous extents.

@dave I may be thinking of the file allocation table in NTFS, or whatever they call it. MFT. Can that be expanded?

Yes,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/master-file-table - and, of course, the needed size of the MFT is based on the number of files, not the number of disk clusters (though obviously the two are often related)

Just tried on a web page emulator with DOS 3.30 and default 47MB hard drive.
As DOS 3.30 supports only partitioning with FDISK up to 32MB, it could be partitioned to 32MB C: drive and about 15MB D: drive in an extended partition.
Formatted with no special parameters, C: uses 512 byte sectors, 4 sectors per cluster for 2KB cluster size. Verified by creating a 3-byte file with echo and using CHKDSK to see it takes 2048 bytes. There's two FAT copies. Total sectors on disk is 65467. There's 64 sectors per FAT. So there is about 16366 clusters, meaning a FAT16 system. Each cluster takes 2 bytes in FAT so about 32732 bytes per single FAT is needed. Divide that with sector size of 512 and you have 64 sectors for FAT, exactly what DOS stated.
So a 32MB drive needs 64 sectors or 32KB for single FAT, double that to 128 sectors for 64KB for the both FAT copies.
Interestingly, the 15MB D: drive seems to use 4KB cluster size (8 sectors), for 12 sectors per FAT. Which means it uses FAT12 file system. So there is 30277 sectors for 3784 clusters.
With the updated MS-DOS 3.31, it was possible to partition the whole 47MB drive into a single partition, which used 2KB cluster size.
I did not test 20MB drive - it could be formatted as FAT16 or FAT12 depending on the threshold it has for choosing.

THANK YOU! And my conclusion is that 32K probably is too much to cache by default on a 640K system when you also have to cache the data buffers. I miss the times when I had to think about stuff like that. Again, ty.

The size of the FAT depends on the size of the filesystem. In the published MSDOS 4.0 source the calculation is given as:
; We calculate the number of sectors required in a FAT. This is done as:
; # of FAT Sectors = TotalSectors / SectorsPerCluster * # of bytes in FAT to
; represent one cluster (i.e. 3/2) / BytesPerSector (i.e. 512)

(The 3/2 applies in FAT12 filesystems; for FAT16 it is a multiplication by 2).
In MS-DOS 3.3 (other than Compaq DOS) the maximum number of sectors in a filesystem is 65536, so maximum number of sectors required for the FAT would be 65536 / SectorsPerCluster * 2 / BytesPerSector (the last division being rounded up).
The size of the FAT would therefore depend on what cluster size the drive was formatted with, and what sector size was being used -- normally this would be 512 bytes, but in a logically-sectored FAT scheme the sector size could be increased to allow a larger filesystem than 32Mb while still using 16-bit sector numbers.
The size of the FAT (and whether or not there is a second copy -- there almost invariably is) is set at the point the drive is formatted, so the FAT is never fragmented.
On a FAT16 filesystem, the biggest the FAT can get is 128k (2 bytes / cluster, 65536 clusters) but I would expect that only on much larger volumes than the ones created by MSDOS 3.3.
